# как запретить создавать экземпляры класса

Tags: python, python-3.x

знаю что можно запретить методом **__ *new* __**, но не могу понять как

Comment: `__new__` должен вернуть либо созданный объект (можно уже ранее созданный), либо бросить исключение в случае ошибки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я так понимаю, это попытка создать `Singleton` ?. Тогда это можно сделать так:

```
class Singleton:
    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance

s1 = Singleton()
s2 = Singleton()

assert s1 is s2
```